# Is it better to read an entire file in std::string or to manipulate a file with std::ifstream?

Tags: c++, string, ifstream

I am actually developing scientific C++ simulation programs which read data, compute lots of values from them and finally store the results in a file. I wanted to know if reading all the data at once at the beginning of the program is faster than keep accessing the file via `std::ifstream` during the program.

The data I am using are not very big (several MB), but I do not even know what "big" is for a heap allocation...

I guess it depends on the data and so on (and after some test, effectively it depends), but I was wondering on what it was depending and whether there is a kind of general principle we should be following.

Long story short, the question is: does keeping a file opened and using file manipulators is faster than a potentially big heap allocation and using string manipulators?

Comment: Accessing memory is always faster than accessing the disk. It really depends on the amount of data you need to read and the context where you run your program. I remember a fews years ago, that I had to read some data from a file which was around 4MB and, surprise, it would fit in the cache! The speed of the program was greatly enhanced by loading all he data to memory, in my case ;)

Comment: Without measuring, I'd guess that letting `fstream` do the buffering is probably faster than reading everything into memory. It's certainly simpler and more scalable, so do that until you've established that it's a bottleneck. But you should measure, not guess.

Comment: This question is more fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com than Stack Overflow, since you are asking about a code you would like to design/refactor, instead of a code that exists and does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is reading all the data at once at the beginning of the program faster than keep accessing the file via std::ifstream during the program?**  Yes, probably it is.  Keep in mind that working memory is fast and expensive, while storage memory (a hard drive) exists precisely to be cheap at the cost of being slow.

**What is "big" for a heap allocation?** The operating system is going to try to fool your process into thinking that all existing working memory is free.  This is not actually true, and the OS will "swap" one type of memory for the other if some process requests too much memory.  But in principle, you should think that a heap allocation is big if it is comparable to the total size of working memory.

**Does keeping a file opened and using file manipulators is faster than a potentially big heap allocation and using string manipulators?**  No, it is not faster, but it has another advantage: it is memory-efficient.  If you only put the needed data into memory in order to work with them, you are saving memory for all other processes in the machine (which could be other threads of your program, for instance).  This is a very interesting property in order to have scalable software.

Comment: As far as I know ifstream should be buffered so the speed difference might be less than you think. On unix systems all file access is buffered by the operating system which will speed things along.

Comment: @doron: Disk access is an order of magnitude slower than memory access. You can't hand-wave that away with "buffering".

Comment: But isn't reading all the data into RAM just another form of buffering?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [mmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap). This API allows you to map a file descriptor into your address space using the same paging mechanism as is used for RAM. This way you should get both the benefit random access to data while not unnecessarily copying unneeded data into RAM.

Comment: Good point.  Even though the question seems more general (and maybe not entirely on-topic here on SO).

Comment: Haven't thought about it, thanks I will measure using this API

Answer (score 0):

(Expect this to be closed because it is an "opinion based" question.)

My thoughts:

1. This sounds like premature optimization.  Write it the easy way, then optimize if it is too slow.
2. Working in memory is generally thousands of times faster.  Heap allocations slow down based on the *number* of allocations, not the *size* of the allocations.  It does not sound like you are working with a whole lot of data though.
3. If your files are "several MB" then the OS will probably cache it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Reading data from a file in large chunks is a lot faster than many read requests of small size.  For example, 1 read of 10MB is faster than 10 reads of 1MB.

When I optimize file I/O, I read the data into a `uint8_t` buffer and then parse the buffer.  One thorn with this method is reading of text files.  There is a possibility that the text encoded data may span across a buffer boundary.  For example, you have 4 numbers per text line and only 2 are in the buffer (or only 2 digits of the number are in the buffer).  You will have to write code to handle these cases.

If you consider your program as a pipeline, you may be able to optimize futher.  You can implement threads:  a reading thread, a processing thread, and a writing (output) thread.  The reading thread reads into buffers.  When there is enough data for processing, the reading thread wakes up the processing thread.  The processing thread processes the data that was read, and when there is some output, it stores it into a shared buffer and wakes up the output thread.  So with the pipeline model, the data enters the pipe via the reading thread.  At some point in the pipe, the processing thread processes the data.  The writing thread takes the data from the processing thread and outputs it (exiting the pipeline).

Also, organizing your data so it fits into a processor cache line will also speed up your program.